# How to do a callback in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm working on a nodeJS script and I would like to know how to execute a function after an another one.
Because actually i need to save in my database some data and then retrieve them. However for the moment my retrieve is executed before my save :/ 
Have already looked on internet there is a lot of example I tried them but for the moment no one worked ... I should probably do something wrong if somebody could help me on it :)

```
function persistMAP(jsonData, callback) {
  console.log(jsonData);
  //Deck persistance
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      var rowData = new DeckDatabase({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        DeckNumber: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].DeckNumber),
        x: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].x),
        y: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].y),
      });
      rowData.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        for (var i = 0; j = jsonData.Units.length, i < j; i++) {
          (function(i) {
            var unit = new MapDatabase({
              //UnitID:  mongoose.ObjectId(jsonData.Units[i].UnitID),
              UnitID: jsonData.Units[i].UnitID,
              TypeID: Number(jsonData.Units[i].TypeID),
              x: Number(jsonData.Units[i].x),
              y: Number(jsonData.Units[i].y),
              _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jsonData.Units[i].Code + 'dd40c86762e0fb12000003'),
              MainClass: jsonData.Units[i].MainClass,
              Orientation: jsonData.Units[i].Orientation,
              Postion: jsonData.Units[i].Postion,
              Deck: String(rowData._id)
            });

            unit.save(function(err) {
              if (err) return console.log(err);
              console.log('save');
            });
          })(i);
        }

      });

    })(i);
  }
  callback();
}; 



app.get("/Map", function(req, res) {
  console.log("got");

  var urlTempBox = 'http://localhost:3000/MapCreate';
  DeckDatabase.find(null, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw (err);
    }
    if (data.length != 0) {
      MapDatabase.find()
        .populate('Deck')
        .exec(function(err, finalData) {
        res.send(finalData);
      });
    } else {
      request(urlTempBox, data, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          throw (error);
        } else {
          var jobj = JSON.parse(response.body);
          console.log("persist begin");
          persistMAP(jobj, function() {
            console.log('retrieve Done');
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript callbacks like this:

```
User.findById(user_id,function(err,data){
  //Inside this you can call another function.

});

console.log("Hello"); //this statement won't wait for the above statement
```

The more good approach would be use promises.

You can also use async await function to handle asynchronus tasks.

**Async Await Style**

```
   async function getData(){
    let user_data=await User.findById(user_id);
    let user_videos=await Videos.findById(user_data._id);  //user_data._id is coming from the above statement
    }
```

But you can only use await in async methods.
Hope it helps.

Comment: maybe with promise yes but how should I say that my persistence is done to my promise's resolve method